# How to build bar graph or line graph for weekly data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, graph, pandas-groupby

I want to build the week on the x-axis and the count on the Y-axis for both line and bar graph.

MY data in data frame.

```
Date-----------    count 

06-01-2017 18.51    1

06-01-2017 19.11    10

20-01-2017 19.55    20

21-01-2017 20.10    30

22-01-2017 20.10    40

23-01-2017 20.10    50

23-01-2017 20.10    60

29-01-2017 21.33    70
```

Please advice

```
df = data.groupby([ pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W-MON')])['value'].sum().reset_index().sort_values('date')

x= df['date']

y = df['value']

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.plot(x, y, color='skyblue')

ax1.set_xticklabels(x,rotation=90)

plt.show()
```

this is giving me graph for month wise i need for week wise

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses.

Comment: You should look at matplotlib